# Which software to batch join videos AND add a chapter for each?

Tags: video

I have 55 short clips (<1min) that have the same characteristics (only the content and length change) and I want to combine them into one big chaptered video.
I know with QTPro how to combine 2 videos and how to add chapters to 1 file. Now I need a Mac OS X tool that's gonna do it automagically.

Comment: AppleScripting it maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily combine many files into one with free [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-mac.html)'s Batch mode — <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. But it will not automatically add chapters at the start of every clip included.

**Update:** Just checked that you can add chapters manually with free tool [Subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/).

You may also add chapters with usually included with every Mac iMovie app. [Here is how to do it with iMovie'09-11](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=iMovie/9.0/en/mov3ac6b3ff.html) but I believe the latter will re-compress the video degrading quality.